# Increasing hw.pagesize in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, huge-pages

I have a server rocking *FreeBSD 13*.

From [the documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) of `sysctl` I can read that `hw.pagesize` *cannot be changes* on the go.  This makes sense to me as this type of parameter depends on the kernel.

I can read also there this:

```
Some of the variables which cannot  be modified during normal system oper-
ation can be initialized via loader(8) tunables.  This can  for example be
done by setting them in loader.conf(5).  Please refer to loader.conf(5)
for more information on which tunables are  available and how to set them.
```

Sadly I cannot find in the documentation of `loader(8)` nor `loader.conf(5)` any reference to this I need.

In a naive attempt, I just added the `hw.pagesize=...` to my `/etc/sysctl` config file, without any success.  Now, when I run `pagesize` I get my sad `4096` bytes value:

```bsh
jose@miner:~ $ pagesize
4096
```

But, how can I make it larger?  I would like to use 1GB pages in a system, yet I cannot find anywhere how to enable so.

Comment: Do you actually need to change a setting? AFAICT FreeBSD automatically uses huge pages in some circumstances. I doubt that there's an option to systematically use 1GB pages: you wouldn't even be able to boot unless you had an immense amount of RAM.

Comment: I am running a process that _does_ benefit from the 1GB pages.  When I am running that process it cannot detect the large pages being enabled.  I am unaware if they are dynamically used as the process munches memory.  In any case invoking `pagesize` does not return a value higher than 4MB.

Comment: You can check that with `vm.pmap.pg_ps_enabled`. In FreeBSD it is called `superpages`. See [Usenix 2020 paper](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/atc20-zhu-weixi_0.pdf) and references in a previous (unwanted) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500372/74393)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this paper!

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD has fairly well documented `man` pages. I am surprised with your link to `sysctl` that you cannot find the remaining info. Read aboud them using

```
 man man
```

This will show the different sections:

```
  The sections of the manual are:
       1.   FreeBSD General Commands Manual
       2.   FreeBSD System Calls Manual
       3.   FreeBSD Library Functions Manual
       4.   FreeBSD Kernel Interfaces Manual
       5.   FreeBSD File Formats Manual
       6.   FreeBSD Games Manual
       7.   FreeBSD Miscellaneous Information Manual
       8.   FreeBSD System Manager's Manual
       9.   FreeBSD Kernel Developer's Manual
```

In you case you can find the proper pages without specifying the sections.

```
man loader.conf
man loader
```

But you can specify the sections:

```
man 8 loader
man 5 loader.conf
```

And you can find them online as well: [loader(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=loader&sektion=8) [loader.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=loader.conf&sektion=5)

You are close to your solution. The file you are looking for is:

```
/boot/loader.conf
```

If it does not exists simply create it. This is read during bootstrapping. You have already got the syntax right.

If this is new to you then beware of this important notice:

```
 BUGS
     The loader(8) stops reading loader.conf when it encounters a syntax er-
     ror, so any options which are vital for booting a particular system
     (i.e., "hw.ata.ata_dma=0") should precede any experimental additions to
     loader.conf.
```

If you make really bad edits to `/boot/loader.conf` you risk that you system cannot boot. If this happens then you need to boot into "Single User Mode". When booting press a key to get to the boot prompt. At the `boot:` prompt enter `boot -s`. You can then mount your filesystem with `/sbin/mount -ruw /` and edit your config (vi is your friend!).

Comment: Sadly, the `loader.conf` does not work either.  I will give a read to the whole documentation and try to find why that value is not honoured.

Comment: I'm a bit sad that this post is just an elaborate version of mine, but mine is getting downvoted.

Comment: I respectfully disagree but do not wish to take this discussion any further. I did however not downvote your answer.

Answer (score -2):

`man loader.conf` has the following sentence almost at the beginning:

```
 All settings have the following format:

       variable="value"
```

And there is no `/etc/sysctl` file, it is called `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: This won't help since `hw.pagesize` is not changeable.

Comment: I said nothing about `hw.pagesize`.